# Optionally run code if package exists

Tags: haskell

In Python, I can run a bit of code optionally if a given package exists like so:

```
try:
  import asd
  # do something with asd
except ImportError:
  print "no module asd"
```

Is there a Haskell equivalent?

Comment: You could use the while statement to optionally run a program while you have the package it’ll run else the package won’t run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, since module imports are resolved at compile-time with GHC. But if you're using [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/) (and you should be!), you can conditionally depend on a package according to a [configuration flag](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/#configurations), and then use the `CPP` extension to compile code depending on whether or not that dependency is present:

```
#if MIN_VERSION_somepackage(0,0,0)
...code using somepackage...
#else
...code not using somepackage...
#endif
```

This is kind of awkward, though, so I wouldn't recommend using it unless you really need it...

Answer (score 1):

No.  A Haskell compiler will reject any program that imports modules that it can't find, just as it will reject uses of undefined functions.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might be able to use new libraries at runtime if you use [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins).